# Possible dynamic If statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to use if statement to evaluate 2 parameters among a plethora of conditions. I know I can use if statement with AND/OR but I think it will be visually cumbersome to do it in excel.

Is it possible to implement the if statement in VBA dynamically? Meaning I want to check the result of the If statement promptly while changing its conditions -say from a drop down list- in the excel sheet (Without having to open and run the VBA window).

Comment: You could use a UDF. Take a look at this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: You can and you can even run macros from changing dropdown menus so the possibilities are near on endless.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **conditional formulas** as explained in the [office-support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-conditional-formulas-ca916c57-abd8-4b44-997c-c309b7307831).

This way you can combine multiple conditionals in separate cells like `=age > 21` named as "is_adult" and `=(gender = "male")` named as "is_male" in your dropdown(s) or combine their results `=AND(is_adult; is_male)` named "is_adult_male".

This pre-evaluated conditionals you can use in combination with a dropdown-list.

Then use the dropdown list's selected value (named "conditional_formula") in your IF-formula like `=IF(conditional_formula; "true cell value"; "false cell value")` .

Additionally you can use **array forumulas** together with **aggregate functions** like `MIN`, `MAX` like described in following article:
[How to Combine the MIN and IF Functions in an Excel Array Formula](https://www.lifewire.com/combine-the-min-and-if-functions-3123299)